# DOB mysql insert

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I try to insert data from dropdown  (day month year) into my database but i encountered an error please help. 
*DOB* set as a date format in my database.

PS. however, it does insert to my *year* *month* *day* fine without any issue.

Thanks in advance and sorry for poor English skill =(

Below is my php code

```
<?php

require '../ppuyakul/php/db_conn.php';

error_reporting(0);
$message = '';
$year = $_POST['year'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$DOB = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0,$month, $day, $year));



if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['fullname']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password_confirmation']) && !empty($_POST['gender']) && !empty($_POST['country']) && !empty($_POST['state']) && !empty($_POST['city']) && !empty($_POST['day']) && !empty($_POST['month']) && !empty($_POST['year'])):

  // Enter the new user in the database
  $sql = "INSERT INTO assignment2 (fullname,username, email, password, passwordcon, gender, country, state, city, day, month, year, DOB) VALUES (:fullname, :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :gender, :country, :state, :city, :day, :month, :year, DOB)";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

  $stmt->bindParam(':fullname', $_POST['fullname']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':password', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
  $stmt->bindParam(':password_confirmation', password_hash($_POST['password_confirmation'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
  $stmt->bindParam(':gender', $_POST['gender']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':country', $_POST['country']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':state', $_POST['state']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':city', $_POST['city']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':day', $_POST['day']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':month', $_POST['month']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':year', $_POST['year']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':DOB', $_POST['year'], $_POST['month'], $_POST['day']);


  if( $stmt->execute() ):
    $message = 'Successfully created new user';
  else:
    $message = 'Sorry there must have been an issue creating your account';
  endif;
endif;

?>
```

And here is my Dropdown code in html

```
<div>
           <p style="display: inline; margin-right: 1%"><span style="font-weight: bold;">DATE OF BIRTH :</span></p>
           <select class="formInputDate" name="day" value="" id="day"></select>
           <select class="formInputDate" name="month" id="month">
                              <option value="1">Jan</option>
                              <option value="2">Feb</option>
                              <option value="3">Mar</option>
                              <option value="4">Apr</option>
                              <option value="5">May</option>
                              <option value="6">Jun</option>
                              <option value="7">Jul</option>
                              <option value="8">Aug</option>
                              <option value="9">Sep</option>
                              <option value="10">oct</option>
                              <option value="11">Nov</option>
                              <option value="12">Dec</option>
            </select>
            <select class="formInputDate" name="year" value="" id="year">
            </select>
          </div>
```

Comment: 1. What is the error? 2. What do you expect from `bindParam(':DOB', $_POST['year'], $_POST['month'], $_POST['day'])`?

Comment: This doesn't look right... `:month, :year, DOB)` A missing colon?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I'm very new to php, which command to print out error because now it just does not insert data into database but did not show anything,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line :

```
 $stmt->bindParam(':DOB', $_POST['year'], $_POST['month'], $_POST['day']);
```

to :

```
 $stmt->bindParam(':DOB', $_POST['year'].'-'. $_POST['month'].'-'. $_POST['day']);
```

The reason is because DATE format expects a properly format date like YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply, I tried it out but still doesn't work, im thinking if there is something to do with

`$year = $_POST['year'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$DOB = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0,$year, $month, $day));`

like I'm not sure that it is necessary to declare the variable or not,
I'm very new to php =( @Simos Fasouliotis

Comment: I actually fix it, by declare this first `$DOB = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( $_POST['year'].'-'. $_POST['month'].'-'. $_POST['day']));` 

then 

`$stmt->bindParam(':DOB', $DOB);` 

thanks so much for your help ^^"